# Is it possible to not show Google play games logo when logging into Google play games

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I implemented Google login by using GoogleSignInClient class and added request scope Games.SCOPE_GAMES.
Because of using the leader board, achievement.

But I don't want to show Google play games logo like that attachment image when Google Play login. Is it possible?

[image]

[image]

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestServerAuthCode(client_id)
                .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();


mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the terms and conditions you can not do any modification or remove the Logo

Answer (score 0):

It is possible use below code. (Connecting Popup Remove)

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder gsoBuilder = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);

Games.GamesOptions gamesOpt = Games.GamesOptions.builder().setShowConnectingPopup(false).build();
GoogleSignInOptions gso = gsoBuilder.requestId().addExtension(gamesOpt).build();
```